# To convert a property in maven pom file and copy it to a particular location

Tags: maven-3

I want to replace all dots in project.version property with underscore  i.e     5.7 -->5_7 in my maven pom.xml and copy only the folder having the replaced value while packing it as jar i.e src/main/resources/5_7 to db/oracle/5_7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things in Maven don't work like that exactly.

If you'd like to do this via the [`maven-resources-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/), then this would not be possible.

As a workaround, you might end up wanting to use the [`maven-antrun-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) and doing the property-changing and copying from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<plugins>
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>regex-property</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>regex-property</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <name>tag.version</name>
              <value>${project.version}</value>
              <regex>\.</regex>
              <replacement>_</replacement>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
          <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-resources</id>
            <!-- here the phase you need -->
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/extraresources</outputDirectory>
              <resources>
                <resource>
                  <directory>src/main/resources/${migration}</directory>
                    <targetPath>db/oracle/${migration}</targetPath>
                </resource>
              </resources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
<plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now, you can use `maven-resources-plugin` to copy files to target and use properties from your pom.xml without any issue.

All you have to do is to add

```xml
<filtering>true</filtering>
```

within the respective  tag to enable this type of variable replacements.

Then you use placeholders like `@project.artifactId@-@project.version@.jar` and these get converted to the actual values while copying.